# how to get high occurring variable from a table using SAS?

Tags: sas, dataset, sas-macro

I have a table as below

```
level1      level2
furniture   chair
furniture   chair
furniture   table
food        pizza
```

I want to get unique level 1 variable and highest occurring level 2 variable for that variable. Output:

```
level1      level2
furniture   chair
food        pizza
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Summarize data to get counts, PROC FREQ.
2. Sort into order to get the counts descending by level1.
3. Use a data step and BY group processing to get the first observations for each level1.

   ```
   proc freq data=have order = freq;
   table level1*level2 / out=counts;
   run;

   proc sort data=counts;
   by level1 descending Count;
   run;

   data want;
   set counts;
   by level1;
   if first.level1;
   run;
   ```

Comment: You should remove level2 from the BY statement in the data step. I'll correct the code.